# como puedo separar este objeto de la siguiente manera:

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, objeto

tengo el siguiente objeto

```
{
  id_carrito: 10,
  id_producto: [ '1', '2' ],
  precio: [ '300', '555' ],
  cantidad: [ '2', '4' ]
}
```

y quiero separarlo asi para hacer inserciones en mysql:

```
{ id_carrito: 10, id_producto: '1', precio: '300', cantidad: '2' }
{ id_carrito: 10, id_producto: '1', precio: '555', cantidad: '4' }
```

Comment: ¿Has intentado algo?

Comment: ¿Qué versión exacta de MySQL Server está usando?.

Comment: La segunda línea no tiene id de producto 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto un poco raro lo que quieres lograr pero iterando el objeto de la siguiente manera obtendrás **por ahora** lo que deseas

```
const obj = {
  id_carrito: 10,
  id_producto: ['1', '2'],
  precio: ['300', '555'],
  cantidad: ['2', '4'],
};

const newArray = [];

for (const index in obj.id_producto) {
  newArray.push({
    id_carrito: obj.id_carrito,
    id_producto: obj.id_producto[index],
    precio: obj.precio[index],
    cantidad: obj.cantidad[index],
  });
}
```

newArray tendra la siguiente salida:

```
[
  { id_carrito: 10, id_producto: '1', precio: '300', cantidad: '2' },
  { id_carrito: 10, id_producto: '2', precio: '555', cantidad: '4' }
]
```